# tabulator list editor expands up instead of down

Tags: javascript, tabulator

This is doing my head in ! If I try the example on http://tabulator.info/examples/5.3 the list editor expands down like this:

[image: from the example page]

They use the following code for this:

```
{title:"Location",
    field:"location", 
    width:130,
    editor:"list", 
    editorParams:{
        autocomplete:"true",
        allowEmpty:true,
        listOnEmpty:true,
        valuesLookup:true}}
```

However, My code looks like this

```
{title:"unite",
             field:"unite",
             editor:"list",
             editorParams:{
                 values:Object.values(units)}
            }
```

And does this (in the same browser):

[image: my code here]

I can't understand why on the example page the link editor expands down (as needed) and in my code it goes up and beyond the page, so I can't select the top most items ???

Thank you for your help,

Jouke

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3711

Comment: Thank you, Timur. I tried every possible way; removing margins and adding popupContainer:true to all sorts of containers, but nothing works. I'm sure I do something wrong. I'll try to make a minimal example.